# A question regarding Hatcher's exercise problem

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm studying Hatcher's algebraic topology, and stuck at a question.[image]

Here what I understand is that the question requires me to describe RP^n as a quotient of a delta complex and S^n.  Is my understanding correct? If so, could anyone help me how to do so? I'm having difficulties becuase RP^n or S^n can't be visualized in high dimensions

Comment: This question has been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344880/hatcher-algebraic-topology-delta-complex

Comment: I would start by defining the $\Delta$ structure on $S^n$ (since Hatcher doesn't tell you what it is). $S^n_k$, the set of $k$-faces of $S^n$ has $2^{k+1}$ elements. Try to describe them, and the boundary maps $S^n_{k+1} \to S^n_k$.

Once you're done, describe the antipodal map as a $\Delta$-map, and then try to quotient by it.